# Resetting an array of JButton Labels and making all active again

Tags: java, jbutton

when i play my game i allow the user to click the buttons which then sets a o or an x as the label and then each button becomes in active as to not allow the user to clik it again and again

however when i get to 9 goes and its a draw a message box pops up and says draw but i cant seem to get the buttons to restore themselves to the original state to allow for a new round

what could you suggest

edit:

i have no idea why i didnt create a loop to do this  cheers guys i will try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course hard when you didn't show us any code, what did you try that didn't work?

I would think a plain old loop should do the trick.

```
JButton buttons[];

for(JButton b : buttons)
{
  b.setText("");
  b.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I hope that is the proper looping syntax, it's been a while since I worked in Java.

Answer (score 0):

[JButton](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html).[setText("")](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText(java.lang.String)), [JComponent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).[setEnabled(true)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled(boolean)).